# Google, Bing, Azure Maps off-line

Tags: c#, google-maps, asp.net-mvc-4, bing-maps, azure-maps

I am building an application that can use Google, Bing and Azure maps to display my data.

I'm now at the stage that I need to look into how to display these maps when I don't have an internet connection.

Do you know how I can use these map services while off-line?

Is it possible to cache the information perhaps?

Comment: What information do you want to store? map tiles can be donloaded i guess, but, depending on the region you want to download (US, EU, single country only, neighborhood, etc.), those tiles need a lot of disc space. Routing, geocoding and similar services need a map server ... 
It's not clear what you are asking for. Voted for close, because your question is way to broad.

Comment: That might just work, thank you

The map will have all the information required on the first load.  Additional map pins and popup's will be added when offline.  These pins and popups only effect the local map for the user.

Comment: Note that all of these platforms do not allow mixing of their data with other mapping platforms

Answer (score 4):

If you are targeting the Windows platform, the UWP map control fully supports offline usage.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/maps-and-location/display-maps

Using the bing maps web control offline is not supported (and storing bing maps tiles offline is against the terms of use).